# Conjure-up with OpenStack and Juju

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 with conjure-up and OpenStack and I want to know how to develop a python cloud-based application with OpenStack and Juju.

Here is my main question:

- After creating my model using Juju, what are the next steps needed to build my application?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is way to broad and beyond the scope of a single Q&A on askubuntu.com.  However, you might look to resources like:

- Juju: https://jujucharms.com/
- Canonical Kubernetes: https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/kubernetes
- Conjure Up:  http://conjure-up.io/
- Ubuntu Cloud on Twitter:  https://twitter.com/ubuntucloud